# border-radius is incorrect code?

Tags: html, css

I'm using Programmer's Notepad, in my .css I've got the following:

```
tr#menu
{
border-style:solid 5px black;
background-color:#0099FF;
border-radius:25px;
}
```

border-radius is highlighted red as incorrect code?

Update - Code don't work in browser.
Update - I don't get a black border either :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a “bug” in a certain application.

Comment: Funny, it's the `border-style` declaration that's incorrect and not the `border-radius` declaration.

Comment: Maybe it's just out of date?

Comment: it's not a bug, the css don't work in the browser.

Comment: @Quentin: But even if there is no visible border, the box should still be rounded anyway, and assuming the background-color is visible against the parent element, this rounding effect should be visible.

Comment: @BoltClock — Good point (aside from the issues that might exist around changing the shape of a table row).

Comment: @Quentin: Oh yeah, there's that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not exist in CSS level 2.

It is fine in CSS level 3.

---

> Update Code don't work in browser.

See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius):

> The effect of border-radius on internal table elements is undefined in
>   CSS3 Backgrounds and Borders, but may be defined in a future
>   specification. CSS3 UAs should ignore border-radius properties applied
>   to internal table elements when ‘border-collapse’ is ‘collapse’.

Note that `tr` elements are, by default, internal table elements.

---

> Update - I don't get a black border either :(

You've confused the `border` shorthand property with the `border-style` property.

Comment: Are you saying Programmer's Notepad only "supports" CSS level 2?

Comment: That would be a logical inference given the information provided in the question. It does raise the question of why it isn't complaining about `border-style` though.

Comment: I've changed the css to target the TD's rather than TR, makes sense really for what I wanted, works but Prog notepad still don't like it, this is for nothing major, I know how to use Dreamweaver, this is easier to use for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just see if it works when you open a browser. Maybe Programmer's Notepad has an old version? Border-radius should work.

Answer (score 0):

Programmers notepad isn't updated to include all the CSS3 keywords in the css.cscheme file for syntax highlighting.

The CSS will still work in compatible browsers. I would suggest getting a different more updated text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-radius` to your `WebFiles.scheme` file